# How to delete csv values outside a radius

Tags: python, pandas

I am a bit new to python and especially pandas. I have a csv file that has a table with values and their corresponding longitude and latitude that looks like this:

```
Longitude       Latitude    Value
-123.603607     81.377536   0.348
-124.017502     81.387791   0.386
-124.432344     81.397611   0.383
-124.848099     81.406995   0.405
-125.264724     81.415942   --
...            ...         ...
```

I am interested in finding all values whose longitude and latitude lies within a 0.7 lon/lat radius from the point -111.55 lon, 75.6 lat by removing all rows whose longitude/latitude are located outside of a radius. There was a question similar to this posted a few days ago, but I haven't found a way to do it yet.

My current code uses the distance formula but ends up in an error:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import math
df =pd.read_csv(r"C:\\Users\\tx163s\\Documents\\projectfiles\\values.csv")
drop_indices = []
for row in range(len(df)):
   if(math.sqrt(abs(-111.55 - df[row]['Longitude'])*abs(-111.55 - df[row]['Longitude'])+abs(75.6-df[row]['Latitude'])*abs(75.6-df[row]['Latitude'])) > 0.7):
      drop_indices.append(i)
df.drop(drop_indices)
df.to_csv(r"C:\\Users\\tx163s\\Documents\\projectfiles\\values.csv")
```

Comment: Can you write out the formula instead of us having to derive it from your code.

Comment: The formula is in the if function. It deletes the row when sqrt((-111.55-longitude)^2+(75.6-latitude)^2))>0.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't edit my comment (too late), so I post the whole modified code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import math
df =pd.read_csv(r"C:\\Users\\tx163s\\Documents\\projectfiles\\values.csv")
drop_indices = []
for row in range(len(df)):
   if ((-111.55-df[row]['Longitude'])**2+(75.6-df[row]['Latitude'])**2) > 0.49:
      drop_indices.append(i)
df.drop(drop_indices, axis=0, inplace=True)
df.to_csv(r"C:\\Users\\tx163s\\Documents\\projectfiles\\values.csv")
```

The pb in your initial code was the missing 'inplace=True' to modify the incoming df instead of returning a new df with dropped rows.

The other modification avoids repeated access to `df` as well as the use of `abs` and `sqrt`. The trick is: sqrt(x^2) > 0.7 is equivalent to x^2 > 0.49

Finally note that using Euclidian distance on spherical coordinates (longitude,latitude) is not very pertinent, but that is another question...

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would to be to use [Haversine Formula](https://pypi.org/project/haversine/), run it for all the coordinates and make a condition to remove all the coordinates greater than the radius distance.

I would also incorporate threading if I had a large data set.

Approach could also be taken from Monte Carlo Pi prediction, being approx but it could be made highly parallel and fast. [See here](https://www.hackster.io/arthur-brown/estimating-pi-with-the-monte-carlo-method-fb9676)

Good luck.

Comment: Threading will make no difference to processing speed due to the GIL

Comment: @roganjosh, this is a debatable topic and after release of python 3.2 GIL has been improved dramatically, regardless of that if i dare to say Dask could also be used to make it like parallel or fast. However I would love to discuss GIL with you some place other than comments. Cheers!